# HTML5 Mutliple tracks at once, with one controls

Tags: jquery, html, audio

What I'm trying to achieve is: Using one controls of audio-player, play 2-3 or more tracks at once. This means that for example if I have 1track.mp3, 2track.mp3, when play button is clicked, they both get played etc. Unfortunatly i cant share any code now, because i really dont have anything that looks good, if you can give a raw example it would be great! Cheers!
P.s: jquery might be used, its okey. But flash is not allowed!

What I have now is two  tags, which is incorrect...

```
<audio id='player_audio' controls>
  <source src="fhg_pianomp3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="fhg_pianomp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="fhg_bassmp3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="fhg_bassmp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> 
<audio id='player_audio1' controls>
  <source src="fhg_bassmp3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="fhg_bassmp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to generate own buttons and trigger the play and pause events via javascript.

```
var player1 = document.getElementById('firstPlayer');
var player2 = document.getElementById('secondPlayer');
document.getElementById('yourPlayButton').onclick = function() {
  player1.play();
  player2.play();
}
```

Comment: Ye but that way, i need to have 2 seprate <audio> tags

Comment: You also could generate the two audio elements using javascript. So they wouldn't be in the DOM. `var player1 = new Audio();`

Comment: and how i can append source to new generated player :?

Comment: `player1.setAttribute('src','yoursource.mp3');`